# Android Service : bind or start?

Tags: android, service

In what cases should I start Service and in what case bind Service? For example - an android client for Music Service? Are the any differences in the priority for the System;are the any  common rules; anything else?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `startService()` for services which will run independently after you start them.  Music players are a good example.  These run until they call `stopSelf()` or someone calls `stopService()`.

You can communicate with a running service by sending Intents back and forth, but for the most part, you just start the service and let it run on its own.

Use `bind()` when the service and client will be communicating back and forth over a persistent connection.  A good example is a navigation service which will be transmitting location updates back to the client.  Binders are a lot harder to write than intents, but they're really the way to go for this usage case.

Regarding the priority: When all activities of a process lose their visibility, the process becomes a *service process* if it hosts a service which was started with `onStart()`, otherwise it becomes a *background process*. Service processes have a higher priority than background processes. Further details at the [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

If a service process without visible activity needs a higher priority (e.g. a music player which really should not be interrupted), the service can call `startForeground()`.

Comment: The Google developer tutorial mentions that binding `"...would work well for a music application that needs to bind an activity to its own service that's playing music in the background."` And yet you say that's what startService should be used for. I am commenting because right now I am struggling with the same question: to bind or to start.

Comment: Google developer tutorials are terrible and miss leading.

Comment: Really, either way works. startService() is usually the best choice for a service that will run on its own, and bind() is usually the best choice when your app and the service will be in constant back-and-forth communication. But you could use Intent for back-and-forth communication with a startService() style service, or you could use bind() to launch a service and just let it run. Do whichever way you want. Frankly, binders are a lot of work to write, so I avoid them. You could also use ResultReceiver, which is a convenience wrapper around Binder.

Comment: Just one more point: there's no reason you can't use `startService()` to start a service, but bind to it as well.