# Advantages and Disadvantages of binding vs starting a service in android

Tags: android, service

Yes, I know this is a duplicate: [Android Service : bind or start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713161/android-service-bind-or-start). But as I commented there, the answer given is problematic.

In the [Google Dev Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), binding is recommended as `...would work well for a music application that needs to bind an activity to its own service that's playing music in the background.` Whereas the SO answer I just linked to says that's the very kind of service I would need to start instead of bind to.

Now, I understand the argument for Navigation app, but clearly the score is not settled for things like music streaming. So will someone please clarify a bit more?

The fact that I can bind endlessly and start endlessly would suggest the two methods exist for a reason. More pointedly, for instance, why is music streaming a good example for either?

And again, my main question: What are the advantages and disadvantages concerning binding vs starting? In other words: compare and contrast bindService and startService.

Sorry for the repetitions, but I am trying to capture this as completely as possible so I may get really good answers.

Comment: `bindService()` is much better esp when binding to local Services

Comment: Hi @pskink are you confirming that bindService can do absolutely everything that startService is good for? Or are there cases where startService can accomplish more? Notice I say `accomplish more` because I don't really care much about which one is easier to implement. I want to know in terms of what they can accomplish for me when is startService better and when is bindService better. Thanks for helping.

Comment: yes i can confirm that bond service (esp local one) is a better citizen than started service

Answer (score 2):

As for as I worked & read stuff about `bindService` and `startService` I am explaining the following.

First of all they two have different life Cycle.

```
bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

If you just use `bindService` with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag to create the service and bind, it will create a service for you and bind it to you. Once you `unbindService` the service life will be stopped. ie. Most probably in onStop phase of your main process. So you can use `bindService` to create and bind service if you need it only on demand and close when you don't require. Like the Navigation App as you mentioned. This won't follow regular Service lifeCycle of `onCreate` > `onStartCommand`

```
startService(mIntent);
bindService(mIntent, mConnection, 0);
```

If you want to run the service even if you come out of the Activity then you have to use `startService` and you can bind to it using `bindService` with flag like 0 or `BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT` (means, service is more important than the running client activity). Now you can bind to the service and unbind any number of time, but the service will keep on running (until you kill it). This follows `onCreate` > `onStartCommand`

Your confusion with music app is basically with the use of the app: in Google Dev they might have noted in aspect like when you close your activity the music stops and exits the app (like Youtube). [binding and unbinding is enough]

And the SO might have noted in aspect like the music should continue playing even after coming out of activity (like Google Play Music). [for this you have to start a service and run it forever]. You can stop the service by calling `this.stopSelf()` when you need or `stopService` from an activity.

So you can't say `bindService` is better citizen than the started service.

The service created with bindService won't run after stopping the activity.

Comment: `startActivity()` or `startService()` ?