# Java android Service is not destroyed when I killed my applications

Tags: java, android

This is my service, this service check a WiFi connections :

```
public class WiFiService extends Service {

    private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    //    public Handler handler = null;
    public static Runnable runnable = null;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long delay = 2 * 10 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        executeSomething();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        Log.e("destroyed " , " kill ");
    }

    void executeSomething() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "a" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    String ssid = info.getSSID();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Nie jest właczone" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String ssid = "AndroidAP";
                    String key =  "iawu7483";
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
                    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();
                }
                executeSomething();
            }
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

I started this service in  class App extends Application

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startService(new Intent(this, WiFiService.class));
    }
}
```

But when I killed my application I see that this service worked all the time. How I can finish this service? And started one more time , when I run my application

Comment: write you logic to stop the server in the `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` block of the activity. Here is the activity [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: instead of manually starting service - bind to it. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713161/android-service-bind-or-start

Comment: @RafalMalek I don't understand what I have to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an intent from the destroyed activity to the service to close it :

in your activity :

```
@Override
void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
    intent.setAction("STOP");
    startService(intent);
}
```

in your service :

```
@Override
void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int id){
    if(intent.getAction().equals("STOP")){
        stopSelf();
    }
    // code..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you kill your application the method onTaskRemoved() of Service is getting called.

You can stop your service task from that method. 
And you can again start your service from the launching activity.

I hope it helps. 
Thanks.

Comment: How I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended, `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called. It will be called if the Service is explicitly stopped, but if the process is killed abruptly (it could happen for many reasons) it won't be called.

As it's been pointed out, you could override onTaskRemoved() in order to detect a swipe from recent activities, but this is not the only scenario in which your Service might be killed with no warning.

If you want your Service to be restarted you need to return `START_STICKY` in int [`onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

// You can destroy your service like this

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // stop location updates
    if (mLocationRequest != null && mLocationClient != null) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }

    Log.e("Rajneesh", "Destroy ... ");
}
```